# Error when creating stored procedure to view data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I am having a lot of trouble with the syntax of this stored procedure that is supposed to return All information from a table called Country and is trying to use a parameter for comparison:

```
Create Procedure CountrybyPK (country char(50))
begin
Select * From Country
Where Country.Name=country
end;
```

The error I get states:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 5
```

Comment: I'm speaking from the top of my head so this may not be right but try: `where Country.Name=@country`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a statement delimiter between the `SELECT` statement and `END`.

```
Create Procedure CountrybyPK (country char(50))
begin
Select * From Country
Where Country.Name=country;
end;
```

But since the delimiter would also terminate the whole procedure, you need to use the `DELIMITER` command to switch to another delimiter:

```
DELIMITER $$
Create Procedure CountrybyPK (country char(50))
begin
Select * From Country
Where Country.Name=country;
end$$
```

But since your procedure only has one statement in it, you don't need `begin` and `end` at all, you can just do:

```
Create Procedure CountrybyPK (country char(50))
Select * From Country
Where Country.Name=country;
```